# Cannot center navigation bar's menu items on page while using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the jsfiddle of what I've tried.
I want 'infos shop contact' to be centered at top of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/p1ebz2qv/2/

```
.nav
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center; 
}
.nav-pills
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

(Seems like there would be a padding-left: 0 coming from Bootstrap .nav class?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Bootstrap's [text-center class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) to your nav:

```
<nav class="text-center">
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p1ebz2qv/3/)**

Comment: nice simple answer :D